# Unknown Column error for

Tags: php, sql

I checked everything but given my less than 1 month using PHP i can't seem to get to the bottom of this.  Whenever i use this $sql query it gives me the error:

```
//$startrow is variable
$startrow = 0;

$sql = "SELECT `accounts.full_name`, `image.name` FROM `accounts` LEFT JOIN 
`image` ON `accounts.person_id` = `image.person_id` WHERE 
`accounts.image_set` = '$yes' and `accounts.full_name` LIKE '%$q%' 
LIMIT $startrow, 15";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a table called `image`. Your table is called `face_shot`.

Also, your backticks must surround each part of the name (not the including dot). Or you can omit the backticks completely except for [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

```
SELECT `accounts`.`full_name`, `image`.`name`
FROM `accounts`
LEFT JOIN `image` ON `accounts`.`person_id` = `image`.`person_id`
WHERE `accounts`.`image_set` = '$yes'
AND `accounts`.`full_name` LIKE '%$q%' 
LIMIT $startrow, 15
```

Comment: My bad that was another table.  Its supposed to be image.  But despite that fix it still doesn't work.